# Avoid for-loop to split array into multiple arrays by index values using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

**Input:** There are two input arrays:

```
value_array = [56, 10, 65, 37, 29, 14, 97, 46]
index_array = [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  1,  1]
```

**Output:** I want to split `value_array` using `index_array` without using for-loop. So the output array will be:

```
split_array = [[56, 10, 37, 14],  # index 0
               [65, 97, 46],      # index 1
               [],                # index 2
               [29]]              # index 3
```

Is there any way to do that using `numpy` without using any for-loop? I have looked at [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but cannot figure it out how to do that.

**For-loop:** Here is the way to do that using for-loop. I want to avoid for-loop.

```
split_array = []
for i in range(max(index_array) + 1):
    split_array.append([])
           
for i in range(len(value_array)):
    split_array[index_array[i]].append(value_array[i])
```

Comment: Do you have a working version *with* a loop ?

Comment: @ivan added code with for-loop.

Comment: Since `split_array` is a list with arrays/lists of varying length, you can't avoid Python-level loops (even if it is hidden in the `np.split` function).  The fabelled `no-loop` operations are limited to whole array (or slices) and return whole (numeric) arrays, not lists of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suffice?

#### Solution 1 (Note: for loop is not over the entire index array)

```py
import numpy as np

value_array = np.array([56, 10, 65, 37, 29, 14, 97, 46])
index_array = np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  1,  1])

max_idx = np.max(index_array)
split_array = []

for idx in range(max_idx + 1):
    split_array.append([])
    split_array[-1].extend(list(value_array[np.where(index_array == idx)]))
print(split_array)
```

```
[[56, 10, 37, 14], [65, 97, 46], [], [29]]
```

#### Solution 2

```py
import numpy as np

value_array = np.array([56, 10, 65, 37, 29, 14, 97, 46])
index_array = np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  1,  1])

value_array = value_array[index_array.argsort()]
split_idxs = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sort(index_array)) != 0) + 1)
print(np.array_split(value_array, split_idxs))
```

```
[array([56, 10, 37, 14]), array([65, 97, 46]), array([29])]
```

Comment: Updated my question. I just want to avoid for-loop by taking advantage of `numpy`. Edit: I noticed, your code has for-loop with `max_idx` iteration, instead of `len(value_array)` which is good.

Comment: Result of solution two is missing an empty array, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np

value_array = np.array([56, 10, 65, 37, 29, 14, 97, 46])
index_array = np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  1,  1])

# find the unique values in index array and the corresponding counts
unique, counts = np.unique(index_array, return_counts=True)

# create an array with 0 for the missing indices
zeros = np.zeros(index_array.max() + 1, dtype=np.int32)
zeros[unique] = counts  # zeros = [4 3 0 1] 0 -> 4, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1

# group by index array
so = value_array[np.argsort(index_array)]  # so = [56 10 37 14 65 97 46 29]

# finally split using the counts 
res = np.split(so, zeros.cumsum()[:-1])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[array([56, 10, 37, 14]), array([65, 97, 46]), array([], dtype=int64), array([29])]
```

The time complexity of this approach is *O(N logN)*.

Additionally if you don't care about the missing indices, you could use the following:

```
_, counts = np.unique(index_array, return_counts=True)
res = np.split(value_array[np.argsort(index_array)], counts.cumsum()[:-1])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[array([56, 10, 37, 14]), array([65, 97, 46]), array([29])]
```

Comment: `np.split` still loops - one slice for each returned array in the list.

Comment: @hpaulj Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can use numpy by using arrays :

```
import numpy as np
value_array=np.array(value_array)
index_array=np.array(index_array)
split_array=[value_array[np.where(index_array==j)[0]] for j in set(index_array)]
```